# how to do calculation between a list and a matrix in r

Tags: r

I have a list and a Matrix as per below:

List Y:

```
 $`1`
    V1 V2
 1  1  1
 2  1  2
 3  2  1
 4  2  2

 $`2`
     V1 V2
 5   5  5
 6   11 2

  $`3`
     V1  V2
  7  10   1
  8  10   2
  9  11   1
 10   5   6
```

Matrix Z:

```
     [,1][,2][,3][,4][,5][,6]
[1,]   2   1   5   5  10   1
```

I consider below as points1, points2 and points3 in Matrix Z respectively

points1 -(2,1)

```
        [,1][,2]
    [1,]  2   1
```

points2 - (5,5)

```
        [,3][,4]
    [1,]  5   5
```

points3 - (10,1)

```
        [,5][,5]
    [1,]  10  1
```

I want to calculate the sum of distances between all points in list Y[[1]] and points1, all points in List Y[[2]] and points2 and all points in List Y[[3]] and points 3 in r. How can I do this?

```
  rowsums(|y-z|^2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description,

```
Map(function(y, z) rowSums(abs(y - z[col(y)])^2),
                 Y, split(Z, as.numeric(gl(ncol(Z), 2, ncol(Z)))))
```

Comment: This solution gives the correct desired output thank you so much. After the above calculation is done, how can I get the total sum of the answers altogether [[1]][[2]][[3]] ?

Comment: @DataMiningStudent  If `lst` is the output object, then `sum(unlist(lst))`

Comment: Hi akrun, I have a question. In my question above, List Y is considered as one list i.e List Y[[1]], but how to do it if List Y has 10 list - [[1]] to [[10]] and matrix Z has more than one row?

Comment: @DataMiningStudent  Is it like a `list` of `list`?  Can you post a new question

Comment: Hi I have posted a new question

Comment: Hi Akrun, can you please have a look at my similar question [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298033/how-to-do-calculation-between-a-set-of-lists-and-matrix-with-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It uses `Map` to apply a function to every vector of the two lists passed to `Map`. Note that we cannot simply do

```
Map('-', Y, Z2)
```

because `R` would do the subtractions columnwise, not row by row.

```
f <- function(x, y){
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(x)))
        x[i, ] <- x[i, ] - y
    x
}

Z2 <- split(Z, rep(1:3, each = 2))
Map(f, Y, Z2)
```