# How to do calculation between a set of lists and matrix with multiple rows

Tags: r

I have a  set of list and a Matrix with multiple rows as per below:

For example:

```
 List Y:
[[1]]
 $`1`
    V1 V2
 1  1  1
 2  1  2
 3  2  1
 4  2  2

 $`2`
     V1 V2
 5   5  5
 6   11 2

  $`3`
     V1  V2
  7  10   1
  8  10   2
  9  11   1
 10   5   6


 [[2]]
 $`1`
     x y
  1  1 1
  2  1 2
  3  2 1
  4  2 2
  9  5 5
  10 5 6

 $`2`
    x y
  7 11 1
  8 11 2

 $`3`
   x y
 5 10 1
 6 10 2
```

Matrix Z:

```
     [,1][,2][,3][,4][,5][,6]
[1,]   2   1   5   5  10   1
[2,]   1   1   11  1  10   1
```

I consider below as points1, points2 and points3 in Matrix Z respectively

points1 -(2,1)

```
        [,1][,2]
    [1,]  2   1
```

points2 - (5,5)

```
        [,3][,4]
    [1,]  5   5
```

points3 - (10,1)

```
        [,5][,5]
    [1,]  10  1
```

I want to calculate the sum of distances between all points in list Y[[1]] $'1' and points1 row 1, all points in List Y[[1]] $'2' and points2 row 1 and all points in List Y[[1]] $'3' and points 3 row 1 in r.

Next I want to calculate the sum of distances between all points in list Y[[2]] $'1' and points1 row 2, all points in List Y[[2]] $'2' and points2 row 2 and all points in List Y[[2]] $'3' and points 3 in r. How can I do this?

```
  rowsums(|y-z|^2)

  A <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,10,1,10,2,11,1,11,2,5,5,5,6), ncol=2, 
  byrow=TRUE)
  Y1 <- split(as.data.frame(A),apply(distanceMatrix1,1,which.min))
  Y2 <- split(as.data.frame(A),apply(distanceMatrix2,1,which.min))
  Z1 <- matrix(c(2,1,5,5,10,1), nrow=1, byrow = TRUE)
  Z2 <- matrix(c(1,1,11,1,10,1), nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)

  #to get distanceMatrix 1 & 2 for List Y[[1]] and [[2]]
  ObjCentDist <- function(A, Z1) {
  resultMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(A)[1], ncol=dim(Z1)[2]/2)
  for(i in 1:nrow(A)) {
      for(j in 1:((dim(Z1)[2])/2)) { 
         for(n in 1:nrow(Z1)) { 

         k = (j * 2) - 1
         resultMatrix[i,j] <- sqrt(rowSums((t(A[i,])-Z1[n,k:(k+1)])^2))
        }
      }
    }
   resultMatrix
   }
   distanceMatrix1 <- ObjCentDist(A, Z1)
```

My expected outputs are as folows:
For rowsums(|y-z|^2)

```
  ListY_1_Row1 <- Map(function(y, z) rowSums(abs(y - z[col(y)])^2),
                Y, split(Z2, as.numeric(gl(ncol(Z), 2, ncol(Z)))))

  output between ListY[[1]] and Row 1 from Matrix Z:
  > ListY_1_Row1
    $`1`
    1  2  3  4  9 10 
    1  2  0  1 25 34 

    $`2`
    7  8 
    52 45 

    $`3`
    5 6 
    0 1

    output between ListY[[2]] and Row 2 from Matrix Z:
    > ListY_2_Row2
    $`1`
    1  2  3  4  9 10 
    0  1  1  2 32 41 

    $`2`
    7 8 
    0 1 

    $`3`
    5 6 
    0 1
```

I can only achieve the outputs above if I calculate it manually between each List Y and every one row in Matrix Z , How can I automate it using loops?

Comment: please revise you question. It is unclear what your expected output is.

Comment: Hi Jimbou, I've edited my question to include the expected output. I really hope that my explanation is clear now.

Comment: Much better, but could share R code to create your list `Y`? `dput(Y)` would be great. `dput(Z)` would be nice too.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I've edited my question to include the Y and Z code to get the example input.